# I cannot instantiate the type JsonArray - I am using javax.json lib

Tags: arrays, json

I am trying to instantiate an `JsonArray` in Eclipse that way:

```
String text; // 
JsonArray array = new JsonArray(text);
```

But I get the message: Cannot instantiate the type `JsonArray`

I am using the `javax.json` library, would be that the problem?

I saw other people in forums using at same way `JsonArray`, why I get this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I saw other people in forums using at same way `JsonArray`.

For sure they are not using [`JsonArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) from the [`javax.json`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) package. They might be using [`org.json.JSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) or [`com.google.gson.JsonArray`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html) or any other class.

> Why I get this message?

[`javax.json.JsonArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) is an interface and interfaces cannot be instantiated.

Here are a few examples quoted from the [`JsonArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) API documentation that demonstrate how to use it:

> The following example demonstrates how to create a [`JsonArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) object from an input source using the method [`JsonReader.readArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReader.html#readArray--):
>
> ```java
> JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(...);
> JsonArray array = jsonReader.readArray();
> jsonReader.close();
> ```
>
> The following example demonstrates how to build an empty JSON array using the class [`JsonArrayBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.html):
>
> ```java
> JsonArray array = Json.createArrayBuilder().build();
> ```
>
> The example code below demonstrates how to create the following JSON array:
>
> ```json
> [
>   {
>     "type": "home",
>     "number": "212 555-1234"
>   },
>   {
>     "type": "fax",
>     "number": "646 555-4567"
>   }
> ]
> ```
>
> ```java
> JsonArray value = Json.createArrayBuilder()
>     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
>         .add("type", "home")
>         .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
>     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
>         .add("type", "fax")
>         .add("number", "646 555-4567"))
>     .build();
> ```

Comment: Thank you. Now I introduced the 'org.json' classes and seems to be better. But, what I still do not understand is: why I can not create a 'JSONArray' straight away from a string? As seems to be possible to create an  'JSONObject' like this:                 
'JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(textString);'

Comment: @Douglas You can create an `org.json.JSONArray` instance from a string. However, the string must be a valid JSON array. Try: `JSONArray array = new JSONArray("[1,2,3,4,5]");`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now its working as it should! ;)